# How to increase size of FAB in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to increase size of FAB in flutter without size changing when route changes?

Following is the code for creating a custom FAB in flutter:

```
class FAB extends StatelessWidget {
  const FAB({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      width: 80,
      child: FittedBox(
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            height: 60,
            width: 60,
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              logo,
              color: Color.blue,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.red],
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    blurRadius: 16,
                    color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.64),
                    offset: Offset(0, 12),
                    spreadRadius: -6,
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here I'm resizing the FAB using a fitted box to a desired size.

But the issues is that whenever there is a route change the FAB appears small then becomes big (between route transitions). I think this is because I'm scaling the FAB to a desired size. I tried removing the fitted box and the container wrapping it. Then there is no issue.

Is there a way to scale the FAB without this issue?

This is the issue:
[image]

Comment: have you tried using an animated container so that you can control the behaviour?

Comment: Not sure of that!

Comment: You should try  https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar
https://pub.dev/packages/ff_navigation_bar  packages

Comment: No. I don't want to use that. I have a custom layout. as you can see above.

Answer (score 1):

Add `height` to your container and remove the `FittedBox`

```dart
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
  width: 80,
  height: 80,
  child: FloatingActionButton...
```

Comment: I tried that. then the size of the FAB won't increase!

Comment: Remember that I want to increase the size of FAB along with this!

Comment: I also tried transform.scale and a lot other tricks. I tried removing the FAB and added a custom button in place of FAB (within a stack). Then also there are other issues encountered like gesture not recognised beyond a size, etc... So this is the only way seems working for me. But the issue of changing size when routing changes need to be tackled.